# How to choose the function pointer type?

Tags: c++, templates

In my C++ code, sometimes I have a need to call C functions from certain libraries. Some times these are paired functions, like a locking function followed by a unlocking function. I want to ensure I don't forget to call the unlocking function. So I am trying to write a template class to handle it, but I am unable to get it right.

```
template <class T>
class CInReleaser
{
public:
    CInReleaser(T func) : _func(func) {}
    ~CInReleaser() { _func();}
    T _func;
};

void somefunc()
{
    DATA something;
    // call locking function
    lock_something(something);
    CInReleaser<XXX> release(boost::bind(unlock_something,something));
    .
    .
}
```

The function unlock_something() should get called when somefunc() function ends. However I am unable to predict the type XXX. How can I get this to compile?

Comment: It would be better to do the locking in a constructor and the unlocking in the destructor. Then instantiate one single guard object.

Comment: The locking won't always happen in the same scope. But locking in the constructor doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far instead of XXX? What error messages did you get?

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html

Comment: I think the book by Anthony Williams will be very helpful: [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.amazon.com/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770).  Specifically page 459 discusses the `std::lock_guard` class template in C++11.  Page 64 demonstrates using a `boost::shared_mutex` instead of the `std::mutex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper factory function to exploit function template argument deduction:

```
template<typename T>
CInReleaser<T> makeReleaser(T func) {
  return CInReleaser<T>(func);
}
```

Then later in the code:

```
auto release = makeReleaser(boost::bind(unlock_something,something));
```

Comment: Bingo! This is it. I wanted a simple way to predict the type since the function could be different every time taking different arguments. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that locks in the constructor and unlocks in the destructor.

```
template <class Lock, class Unlock>
struct CInReleaser
{
   CInReleaser(Lock lock, Unlock unlock) : _lock(lock), _unlock(unlock)
   {
      _lock();
   }
   ~CInReleaser()
   {
      _unlock();
   }
};
```

Create a function to help with the syntax of constructing the class.

```
template <class Lock, class Unlock>
CInReleaser<Lock, Unlock> makeCInReleaser(Lock lock, Unlock unlock)
{
   return CInReleaser<Lock, Unlock>(lock, unlock);
}
```

Example usage.

```
void somefunc()
{
   auto releaser = makeCInReleaser(boost::bind(lock_something, something),
                                   boost::bind(unlock_something, something));
}
```

Comment: The lock and the unlock function may not be in the same scope. So this won't do. Also, I need to pass arguments to the function, hence bind is required. Look at the accepted answer, it addressed both requirements.

Comment: @SharathKShetty Good points. I updated my answer to address them.

Answer (score 1):

if you have c++11 support available I would just recommend using a little helper like that

```
class Guard
{
public:
    Guard(std::function<void()> fn) : fn_(std::move(fn)) {}
    ~Guard() { if(fn_) fn_(); }
private:
    std::function<void()> fn_;
};
```

and then you can just use a little lambda to write it like that

```
void somefunc()
{
    DATA something;
    // call locking function
    lock_something(something);
    Guard g([=](){ something->unlock_something(); });
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Interesting use of lambda feature. Not sure I fully understand, but I'll try it and see. Might be useful to know.

Comment: What the Guard class actually does is take any function that has no arguments and returns void. You could pass a global function as well but in the example I just passed a lambda of exactly that type (no arguments, returning void). What to do when the scope exits is now just to be stated inside the lambda (here I just called unlock_something() on the something object but you could put everything in there).

Comment: That part was clear. I am unsure about std::move(), the rvalue reference thing. Although I have read up on it, I never really used it until now.

Comment: The move part is not really that important for the idea here. You could instead just pass fn by reference. I tried to propose a more flexible approach that is why I used a move here. When you specify a lambda or a user defined functor that has lots of state (member variables) there might be a benefit in the move because all the members can potentially be moved. I use move semantics a lot actually and I really enjoy it and I think its really worth having a look at it but for your specific example it just is not necessary.